# Prompting user for only positive number

Tags: java

this basic JAVA program should prompt the user, and print "Negative numbers are not allowed" until user enters a positive number. This must be handled by using while loop. how does it work ? This is my first post in stack overflow.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
        System.out.print("Welcome to Box Price Calculator");
        System.out.print(System.lineSeparator());
        System.out.print(System.lineSeparator());
        
        int boxVol = 20 ;
        double price_each_box = 2.99;
        System.out.print("Bottles :");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numberOfbottles = 1;
        numberOfbottles = input.nextInt();
        
        boolean valid = false;
        
      
        while (input.nextInt() < 0){
            System.out.println("Negative numbers are not allowed");
            numberOfbottles = input.nextInt();
        }       
        
        int box = (numberOfbottles / boxVol);
        System.out.println("Box Needed : " + box);
        double totPrice = (box * price_each_box);
        
        System.out.println("Total Cost : $" + totPrice);
        int leftOver = (numberOfbottles -(box * boxVol));
        System.out.println("Unboxed :" + leftOver);
        
    }  
}
```

Comment: `while ((numberOfbottles = input.nextInt()) < 0) { System.out.println("Negative numbers are not allowed"); }`

Comment: Just to add to Edgar's answer, `nextInt()` (or any of Scanner's `next...` methods) tells the program to wait for input when the input is coming from the keyboard (which it is in this case). So any calls to `nextInt()` should be made only when the program is ready for input. In your code you have `numberOfbottles = input.nextInt();` followed by another `input.nextInt()`, meaning you are asking for input twice before the loop even runs once.

Comment: Thank you  It really saved my time.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are reading and compare again with `input.nextInt()` and not with `numberOfbottles`, inside the while condition. What you should do is to use a `do...while` and compare it with your variable `numberOfbottles`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.print("Welcome to Box Price Calculator");
    System.out.print(System.lineSeparator());
    System.out.print(System.lineSeparator());
    
    int boxVol = 20 ;
    double price_each_box = 2.99;
    
    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
  
    int numberOfbottles;
  
    do
    {
        
        System.out.println("Bottles (Negative numbers are not allowed):");
        numberOfbottles = input.nextInt();
    
    }
    while (numberOfbottles < 0);
    
    int box = (numberOfbottles / boxVol);
    System.out.println("Box Needed : " + box);
    double totPrice = (box * price_each_box);
    
    System.out.println("Total Cost : $" + totPrice);
    int leftOver = (numberOfbottles -(box * boxVol));
    System.out.println("Unboxed :" + leftOver);   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. 